How to extract distinct key values from Json Data When there is a duplicate keys and need only one?
In the below sample json I need to extract only second ocuurance of Parameter_1,Parameter_2, etc rather than first, can anyone help me for the same
{
  "response" :
  [
    {
      "Parameter_1" : "high",
      "Parameter_2" : 100,
      "Parameter_3" : "",
      "Parameter_4" : null,
      "Parameter_5" : "Pune",
      "address" :
      {
        "address" :
        [
          "India"
        ]
      },
      "addressElements" :
      {
        "Parameter_11" : null,
        "Parameter_12" : "250",
        "Parameter_13" : null,
        "Parameter_14" : null,
        "Parameter_15" : "India",
        "Parameter_16" : "LN",
        "Parameter_17" : null,
        "Parameter_18" : null,
        "Parameter_19" : null,
        "Parameter_20" : null
      }
    },
    {
      "Parameter_1" : "high",
      "Parameter_2" : 100,
      "Parameter_3" : "",
      "Parameter_4" : null,
      "Parameter_5" : "250",
      "address" :
      {
        "address" :
        [
          "India"
        ]
      },
      "addressElements" :
      {
        "Parameter_11" : null,
        "Parameter_12" : "250",
        "Parameter_13" : null,
        "Parameter_14" : null,
        "Parameter_15" : "India",
        "Parameter_16" : "LN",
        "Parameter_17" : null,
        "Parameter_18" : null,
        "Parameter_19" : null,
        "Parameter_20" : null
      }
    }
  ]
}

Expected Resultset:
{
  "response" :
  [   
    {
      "Parameter_1" : "high",
      "Parameter_2" : 100,
      "Parameter_3" : "",
      "Parameter_4" : null,
      "Parameter_5" : "250",
      "address" :
      {
        "address" :
        [
          "India"
        ]
      },
      "addressElements" :
      {
        "Parameter_11" : null,
        "Parameter_12" : "250",
        "Parameter_13" : null,
        "Parameter_14" : null,
        "Parameter_15" : "India",
        "Parameter_16" : "LN",
        "Parameter_17" : null,
        "Parameter_18" : null,
        "Parameter_19" : null,
        "Parameter_20" : null
      }
    }
  ]
}


You have tagged this with Oracle 11g, which doesn't have any built-in support for JSON. So, how are you currently handling JSON values (a third-party library, regex, something else?) and how have you tried to achieve this task? You've also referred to individual key/value pairs, but do you actually want the entire second element of the array, or data from both elements merged somehow?

Need entire second array, I have try it with JSON_TABLE( Json, '$'COLUMNS) ,but this returns only there's single json array for case of duplicate it is not working

As @AlexPoole asked... what is your oracle version ? You tagged oracle11g but JSON_TABLE was not available in that version. What version you tag impacts the answer. Also please update your question with exactly what you have tried.

My Oracle Database version is 19c.

Use JSON_TRANSFORM for this (docs), in your case the KEEP operation does the trick:
with json_doc AS
(SELECT
'{
  "response" :
  [
    {
      "Parameter_1" : "high",
      "Parameter_2" : 100,
      "Parameter_3" : "",
      "Parameter_4" : null,
      "Parameter_5" : "Pune",
      "address" :
      {
        "address" :
        [
          "India"
        ]
      },
      "addressElements" :
      {
        "Parameter_11" : null,
        "Parameter_12" : "250",
        "Parameter_13" : null,
        "Parameter_14" : null,
        "Parameter_15" : "India",
        "Parameter_16" : "LN",
        "Parameter_17" : null,
        "Parameter_18" : null,
        "Parameter_19" : null,
        "Parameter_20" : null
      }
    },
    {
      "Parameter_1" : "high",
      "Parameter_2" : 100,
      "Parameter_3" : "",
      "Parameter_4" : null,
      "Parameter_5" : "250",
      "address" :
      {
        "address" :
        [
          "India"
        ]
      },
      "addressElements" :
      {
        "Parameter_11" : null,
        "Parameter_12" : "250",
        "Parameter_13" : null,
        "Parameter_14" : null,
        "Parameter_15" : "India",
        "Parameter_16" : "LN",
        "Parameter_17" : null,
        "Parameter_18" : null,
        "Parameter_19" : null,
        "Parameter_20" : null
      }
    }
  ]
}' AS json_data FROM dual
)
SELECT JSON_TRANSFORM(json_data, KEEP '$.response[1]' RETURNING CLOB PRETTY ) AS modified_json FROM json_doc

MODIFIED_JSON                                                                   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "response" :
  [
    {
      "Parameter_1" : "high",
      "Parameter_2" : 100,
      "Parameter_3" : "",
      "Parameter_4" : null,
      "Parameter_5" : "250",
      "address" :
      {
        "address" :
        [
          "India"
        ]
      },
      "addressElements" :
      {
        "Parameter_11" : null,
        "Parameter_12" : "250",
        "Parameter_13" : null,
        "Parameter_14" : null,
        "Parameter_15" : "India",
        "Parameter_16" : "LN",
        "Parameter_17" : null,
        "Parameter_18" : null,
        "Parameter_19" : null,
        "Parameter_20" : null
      }
    }
  ]
}


Great, Thanks. it works. Suppose there are multiple Parameter_2 with multiple values and I need Max, how can I select that those ?

That is a vague question - and pretty different from this original question. If you ask followup questions in the comment,  then only I can see that update, no one else in the community. So I'd go ahead and check the docs (thats what I did) and try it myself (that's what I did too !). If you need help then post another question for anyone in the community to pick up and answer. I think this question is answered.

Yes, Thanks for your help.
